# memory usage optimization / management in Kotlin(JVM)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, kotlin

Below is a program that counts the inversions in the array for `n*log(n)` - in this regard, there is nowhere better, but a lot of memory is spent.

Is there any way to optimize memory usage in this program?

```
import java.lang.Integer.min
var inversions: Long = 0

fun main(){
    val length = readLine()!!.toInt()
    val inputArray = readLine()!!.split(' ').map(String::toInt).toMutableList()
    mergeSort(inputArray, 0, length - 1)
    println(inversions)
}


fun merge(array: MutableList<Int>, left: Int, center: Int, right: Int){
    val amount = right - left + 1
    val tempArray = MutableList(amount) {0}
    var i = left ; var j = center + 1 ; var t = 0
    while (i <= center && j <= right){
        tempArray[t] = min(array[i], array[j])
        if(min(array[i], array[j]) == array[i]) i +=1
        else{
            j += 1
            inversions += center + 1 - i
        }
        t += 1
    }
    if(i > center)
        while (j <= right){
            tempArray[t] = array[j]
            j += 1; t += 1
        }
    else
        while (i <= center){
            tempArray[t] = array[i]
            i += 1; t += 1
        }
    t = 0
    for(index in left..right){
        array[index] = tempArray[t]
        t += 1
    }
}

fun mergeSort(array: MutableList<Int>, left: Int, right: Int){
    if (left < right){
        val center: Int = left + (right - left) / 2
        mergeSort(array, left, center)
        mergeSort(array, center + 1, right)
        merge(array, left, center, right)
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to improve memory usage is to use actual arrays -- an `IntArray` -- instead of a `MutableList`.

Answer (score 0):

(This probably won't have a single complete answer, so I feel justified in posting just an initial thought here :-)

One thing you could would be to reuse a single `tempArray` instead of creating a new one in each invocation of `merge()`.  It'd take slightly more work to initialise, but that should avoid a shedload of temporary objects.

(That should be safe coz `merge()` doesn't recurse.  You could create it in `main()`, and pass it as a parameter into `mergeSort()` and from there into `merge()`.  Or you could make it ‘static’, i.e. put it in a companion object or top-level field.  Though the latter case would prevent it working if called from multiple threads; to fix that, stash it in a `ThreadLocal`.)